# How to use regex to grab a substring

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string

```
{  "access_token": "1234-1234-1234-1234-1234",  "expires_in": 9998,  "refresh_token": "abc-abc-abc-1234",  "token_type": "test"}
```

I only want to grab the access_token value (1234-1234-1234-1234-1234).
I have tried creating a substring like this, and it worked

```
String s2 = result.substring(20,57);
```

The problem I am having is that "access_token" will not always be listed first in the string, and the value will not always be the same length. Is there a way I can make sure this value is always grabbed using regex?

I haven't used regular expressions much, so here is where I am stuck. I tried the below, but it selects too much.

```
(?i)"access_token":\s\S(.*)",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, just grab the datas which exists next to the access_token through capturing group.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)\"access_token\":\s*\"([^\"]*)\"").matcher(s);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fG9nW8/1)